# App Icon with transparent background doesn't appear

Tags: android, background, icons, transparent, android-launcher

I use this image like ic_launcher for my application

[image: ic_launcher]
<sub>(source: [fotohost.by](https://web.archive.org/web/20130915140258/http://www.fotohost.by/pic_b/13/09/13/d5c4ee67cf04f11695d9078555ce716f.png))</sub>

In my application icon is displayed without background

[image: my application]

But in my [GO launcher EX](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gau.go.launcherex) it's displayed with background

[image: go launcher]
<sub>(source: [fotohost.by](http://www.fotohost.by/pic_b/13/09/13/b380bce7dff03e48a2cf42702a5f630d.png))</sub>

In what may be the problem?

Comment: That is no problem. In my phone when i test apps whose icon has a transparent background, it is ok, but when i test it in my friend's phone the icon comes up in a box type thing similar to yours so this is no issue.

Comment: @eric247 in last screenshot you can see another app without background

Comment: Oh now a days WOLVERINE can do coding also !!! :)

Comment: BTW in Go launcher there is an option to enable app icon base. You have to disable it.

Comment: @PrivateModifier thx, if you post your answer, i will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- **Go launcher** provides the functionality to `enable/disable` app icon base .
  You have to disable it.

Comment: But why the other icons appear without a background without disabling this option in Go launcher?

Comment: Let me check it in My device and then tell you.

Comment: Thank you, I will wait for a response

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is a change made by a theme of the launcher.

Comment: What shall i edit/add to the application theme, so that the icon should be displayed transparent?